# Contribution of observation for estimation of coefficients in Linear Regression

Tags: r, regression, machine-learning, probability, distributions

We know that, in order to estimate the vector of coefficients $ \beta $, we have many options.

We can use OLS estimators, obtained minimizing the *squared loss function*.

In this case, we would give the same weight (1) to all the observations in the estimation, that is: regardless of the residual, each observation has the same contribution.

Otherwise, we could opt for robust regression and use huber estimators: in this case, the weight of each observation would be equal to 1 if the observation has a residual in [-2,2], then the weight gets smaller as the residual value gets bigger.

My question is: what about **L1-norm**? When we use LAD estimators, the contribution of each observation is always the same (=1) even if the observation is an outlier (as it happens for OLS estimation)?

Comment: Are you asking about [quantile regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=quantile+regression)?

Comment: It would be first necessary to establish the exact sense in which you're saying that a Huber estimate gives an observation less weight and in particular how much weight we are according it. Presumably then we could perform a similar calculation. With a pure location estimate and taking the usual "weighted average" sense, the relative weight to an observation in a Huber estimate (for a total weight of n, say) is a little *higher* for values in the middle range and lower further out. In that sort of sense with a median (still talking about pure location estimation), ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... the corresponding weight in a weighted average is highest for the middle observation(s) and drops off like $1/|x-\theta|$, for the usual $\psi$ influence function, so that the total contribution to the thing being minimized remains at $\pm 1$ for a median. If this is the intended sense, you're looking at a weight function like $w(x)=\psi(x)/x$, but things are a bit more complicated in a regression context (where the influence - due to outlyingness in x-space) comes in as well).